# Different JSessionID passed for different call within a session

Tags: jmeter, jsessionid

In Jmeter, I have a thread group with 20 http sampler, added HTTP Cookie manager and session is been handled through JSESSIONID.

When I run a script for multiple users with > 10 threads, the first few threads are running properly, thereafter some HTTP samplers of other threads are failed with an error (on the web page): "Your Session is logged out. Please close current window and try login to the application once again."

When I did further analysis, different JSESSIONIDs are passed in between within the same thread.

Please have a look on how a different session id passed for the samplers in same threads and provide a solution for this.

Note: When I run this for a minimal number of users like 2, I don't get this issue.

Comment: Check exactly where the SessionID is changed. Then check the response of previous requests. There's maybe a response with code 200, meaning there's no problem, but the action has an error and the response is redirecting the page to the main URL.

Answer (score 0):

Two options available

1. If you are using URL redirects And come back to main url,you may get different jsessionid And its depend on your server configuration you have,you need to use proper regular expression to extract the session and to bind in next call
2. If you are using same credentials for various threads And if your server config don't have the capability to manage it you may get various jsessionid